# Kashrus in nasal vaccinations

Tags: kashrut-kosher, medicine

In the UK, the influenza vaccination contains pork.

> The nasal flu vaccine does contain hydrolysed gelatine derived from pork as one of its
> additives. Gelatine is commonly used in a range of pharmaceutical products, including
> many capsules and some vaccines. The gelatine used in Fluenz is a highly purified
> product used to stabilise live viral vaccines.
> https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/364143/Influenza_vaccine_and_porcine_gelatine_2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiHvdTR2cbsAhWIJcAKHeqmD_sQFjABegQIARAF&usg=AOvVaw1i84mTUXfbE9X9gEoK2vBh&cshid=1603318356030

**Is this a Kashrus problem?**

**The vaccine is administered to children via nasal spray (not sure if it makes a Halachic difference)**

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45495/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50906/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89376/759

Comment: This would only be a question according to those, like the gra, who believe sicha kishtia.

Comment: Obviously this question only applies to vaccines that don't save lives, which is very few if any of them

Comment: @Heshy I doubt most flu vaccinations in children qualify as bona fide pikuach nefesh.

Comment: Heshy I'm not sure if preemptive measures like vaccines can be considered 'pikuach nefesh', especially in the case of mass immunizations to kids for influenza which wouldn't be deadly to kids to begin with.